# Create a stacked percentage column

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a collection of data like this :

```
var data = [
      {"p301a":"10","p301b":"7","p301c":"7","p301d":"3","p301e":"8","p301f":"8","p301g":"8","p301h":"8","p301i":"8","p301j":"8","p301k":"8","p301l":"8","p301m":"8","p301n":"8","p301o":"8","age":"31-40 years","profesion":"2","position":"2"},
      {"p301a":"5","p301b":"4","p301c":"4","p301d":"4","p301e":"4","p301f":"4","p301g":"4","p301h":"4","p301i":"4","p301j":"4","p301k":"4","p301l":"4","p301m":"4","p301n":"4","p301o":"4","age":"24-30 years","profesion":"2","position":"2"},
      {"p301a":"8","p301b":"8","p301c":"3","p301d":"9","p301e":"9","p301f":"4","p301g":"9","p301h":"4","p301i":"2","p301j":"9","p301k":"4","p301l":"9","p301m":"4","p301n":"9","p301o":"9","age":"31-40 years","profesion":"1","position":"3"},
      {"p301a":"3","p301b":"3","p301c":"3","p301d":"8","p301e":"9","p301f":"9","p301g":"8","p301h":"9","p301i":"9","p301j":"9","p301k":"8","p301l":"8","p301m":"3","p301n":"3","p301o":"3","age":"31-40 years","profesion":"1","position":"3"},
      {"p301a":"6","p301b":"5","p301c":"5","p301d":"8","p301e":"7","p301f":"5","p301g":"6","p301h":"2","p301i":"6","p301j":"5","p301k":"7","p301l":"7","p301m":"4","p301n":"8","p301o":"3","age":"24-30 years","profesion":"1","position":"2"},
      {"p301a":"8","p301b":"8","p301c":"4","p301d":"4","p301e":"4","p301f":"5","p301g":"4","p301h":"4","p301i":"4","p301j":"4","p301k":"4","p301l":"9","p301m":"9","p301n":"9","p301o":"4","age":"31-40 years","profesion":"2","position":"3"}
    ];
```

From the data I want to create a Stacked percentage column from highchartjs,
With the stipulation of each bar having the number of p301a = 1, p301a = 2 and so on up to 10.
I think it can be done using underscore.js, but I do not know how.

i want to create somthing like this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BfFf.png)

or i want to get data like this :

```
var xAxis: {
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c' ... 'o' ]
},
var series: [{
    name: '1',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 9, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
}, {
    name: '2',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
}, {
    name: '3',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 9, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
}, {
    name: '4',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 9, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
}, ... (until 10)]
```

Sorry for the english
Please help

Comment: Can you explain better what you need ?

Comment: Thank you for responding, 
I want to create a diagram like the image I have listed